# Does Dropout need a validation set to prevent overfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting, validation, dropout

Is it really necessary to use a validation set to avoide overfitting while we are using Dropout ?

Comment: Without comparison to a validation set, how would you know that you've successfully prevented overfitting? The probability of masking a unit can be anything between 0 and 1. Is masking masking probability $10^{-10}$ too small (model overfits)? Or too large (model underfits)? How can you know?

Comment: I did not get the  idea of masking units can u please expalin more

Comment: masking units at random is how dropout works. more information: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241645/how-to-explain-dropout-regularization-in-simple-terms/241668#241668

Comment: So did u mean the validation set will help us to find the suitable dropout probability for our model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like typical regularization, dropout is a mechanism to fight overfitting. It doesn't detect it. On the contrary, using a validation set helps you detect it. So, the two have different uses.

Comment: So if we are using Dropout we expect  not having an over-fitted model.in this case do we really need to use a validation set ?

Comment: Dropout fights over-fitting, but it may not prevent it (it's not a silver bullet). Validation set is used for detecting/deciding the overfitting. So, you should use it nevertheless.